# Does R's GLM function default to a one vs all or one vs one or a multinomial approach?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, softmax

If I were to do logistic regression on the iris dataset

```
fit <- glm(species ~ ., data = iris, family = binomial(link = "logit"), subset = c(1:100))
pred <- predict(fit, iris[101:150,-5], type = 'response')
```

Then which type of logistic regression would it be doing? one vs one? All vs all? Softmax?

Let's say I wanted to do all three and compare the results. Are there built in commands to do that? Will I have to write my own function for it? Most importantly, what is R's default?

-Travasaurus Rex

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. `glm(..., family = binomial(link = "logit"))` fits a simple logistic model assuming a binary outcome (e.g. success vs. failure, hence the underlying *binomial* distribution).

If you want to fit a *multinomial* model, you could use `nnet::multinom`

```
library(nnet)
fit <- multinom(Species ~ ., data = iris)
#Call:
#multinom(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)
#
#Coefficients:
#           (Intercept) Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#versicolor    18.69037    -5.458424   -8.707401     14.24477   -3.097684
#virginica    -23.83628    -7.923634  -15.370769     23.65978   15.135301
#
#Residual Deviance: 11.89973
#AIC: 31.89973
```

Comment: If I were to fit a logistic model with more than two responses, the function still works. It breaks down the problem into a series of binary questions, and runs regression on them. My question is how it formatts that question by default. One vs One, or All vs All?

Comment: @Travasaurus in your post title you mention a multinomial model approach. As I explain you’re *not* fitting a multinomial model! So again, it’s not clear what you’re trying to achieve. Do you or do you not want to fit a multinomial model?

Comment: I am, as well as a one vs all logistic regression model (where I compare each class against all other classes in turn and then pick the class with the highest fitted probability from each comparison) then again with a one vs one logistic regression model (where each pairing is tested and evaluated with a voting process). My question, is what is R programing's default method when it is fed more than two classes in a glm model (as is still runs and returns sensical results).

Comment: @Travasaurus I think we're misunderstanding each other. You're *not* fitting a mutinomial model. You're fitting *multiple* binomial logistic models. To fit a multinomial model (where the response variable can take more than 2 classes) you need to use `nnet::multinom`. I assumed you wanted to fit a multinomial model, based on your post's title. In that case `glm` is the wrong approach.